# jQuery not finding elements created by AngularJS in directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using two almost same scenarios, I got two different values:

1st scenario is:

```
<ul id="test1">
   <li>Test 1</li>
   <li>Test 2</li>
   <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
```

2nd scenario is:

```
<ul id="test2">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Inside an AngularJS directive, I want to discover the `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` element.

```
...
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

    var firstLength = $("#test1 li").length; // it gives me 3.
    var secondLength = $("#test2 li").length; // it gives me nothing, 0.
}
```

Why, in the 2nd scenario, I have no `<li>` elements, even they being generated by AngularJS? Thanks!

Comment: Directive is probably being ran before the list is outputted

Comment: link function may be executed before the angular-js engine transformed its template `:/`

Comment: You both are right. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can you kindly answer your own question or kindly close it?

Comment: Don't use jQuery with angular. Use directives.

Comment: why not to use items.length ^^

Answer (score 0):

The content I was trying to get in the link method was executing **BEFORE** AngularJS fill the `<li>` data. So, it won't work properly. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Although the poster is satisfied with knowing why this is occurring, I figured I should add my own solution to resolve this problem in case anyone else runs into this. You can very easily solve the problem by watching the object that is used to generate the elements.

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
  var initialized = false;

  $scope.$watch('items', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (initialized === false) {
      initialized = true;
      //do some stuff
      //i.e. do something with all items or unbind the watch

      return;
    }

    //do some other stuff if it's not the initialization run through
    //i.e. update just the changed item
  }, true);
}
```